# Unhide a Div that's only being showed on hover state

Tags: html, css, hover

I was trying to modify this card from a grid plugin for wordpress, and there's an element that previously was a "read more" anchor element, and trying to save some time i decide it to use it as the green button from the picture below, but the problem is that is only showed in a hover state.

The url is the following one: http://uai.compite.cl

Is there any way to apply a rule for the not hover div? i tried the :not(:hover) but it doesn't seem to work in this case.

Thank you for the help

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] by  posting code in your question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a.tg-link-button {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    -webkit-transform: matrix3d(1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1) !important;
    -moz-transform: matrix3d(1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1) !important;
    -ms-transform: matrix3d(1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1) !important;
    -o-transform: matrix3d(1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1) !important;
    transform: matrix3d(1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1) !important;
}
```

I just added `!important` so it overrides the regular setting.

Comment: This worked perfectly, maintaining the proportion of the hover state.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly you need the hover effect to be on every news div visible without hovering. 
Just add on your css

```
.quito .tg-light .tg-media-button, 
.quito .tg-light .tg-link-button {
   opacity:1;
}
```